# Generate captions for Time Series Data

Tags: python, time-series, caption, timeserieschart, feature-descriptor

I am trying to generate captions for time series data based on increasing/decreasing values.

I have a column with values which change gradually over time (time horizon is irrelevant for now). When we visualize a graph, we make comments like increasing/decreasing, steep curve etc.

I am looking at what libraries are available for the same. Has any research been done in graph captioning/ ts captioning?

Currently juggling with pyts and exploring the quantization options by converting values to small clusters and analysing the so-created bag of words.

As of now, its simply looking at when a value changes direction from inc to dec, halt and generate "increasing" for previous segment and move on. This is an inefficient approach in terms of scaling.

Looking for guidance, suggestions, resources.

Comment: How are you storing the time-series data?

Comment: pandas DataFrame. I have 2 columns, one with dateTime, another with values.

Comment: Are you actually looping over rows? You can simply create a new column which is the difference of two events in a row with `.diff()`, so for e.g. if you have `df['value']` and you want to know when it's increasing or decreasing, you can just do `df['value'].diff()` and wherever that is positive, it's increasing, wherever it's negative, it has decreased.

Comment: There are a lot of different possible summaries of time series data, especially from the autoregressive world, but also simpler things like largest peak-to-peak difference over some time window, exponential moving averages, and so on. This question is a little broad currently, would be better if you could expand on what sort of metrics you need. Also, if you do get more specific on what kind of captions you want (and if the question isn't programming specific) you might consider posting this to the statistics Stack network: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am already creating an additional column with [-1,0,1] mapping of dec, plateau and inc. How do I take a forward? How do I define a window of steep increase, sharp decline etc. I have created bins for now and mapped them to characters. The further the character distance, the higher the rise/fall.

I am looking at identifying how to measure sensitivity of the window where I need to generate captions. I have used PAA to reduce large series to simpler sets to define trends and map them to keywords.
I have posted on the Data Science SE. Will go ahead and post on statsSE too.